# JavaFX FXMLloader resource not found

Tags: javafx

Some things to note before asking my question. I have looked at some youtube videos and blogs on how to pass data from one controller to another and I am under the assumption that you have to use the .openStream() in order to do that if not it breaks my app. So I am trying to pass a string to another controller of mine as you will see below, however prior to this, using the same exact code except without the use of openStream() returns no errors.

However, after using .openStream() I get the following errors

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
```

Method that causes the error

```
private void setupFXMLloader() throws IOException{
        //Set up FXMLloaders
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Parent root = loader.load(getClass().getResource("/smartcal/home/Home.fxml").openStream());
        //Get an instance of the home controller
        HomeController homeController =  loader.getController();
        homeController.initUserSettingsButton(email_field.getText());
        //This method would take a user email and
        //parse it to match database to be loaded onto the calendar
//        homeController.updateCalendarHome();

        //Create a new scene and add css file to it
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
//        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("customfile.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`FXMLLoader.load(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-) method is a `static` method: so if you use that method, it bypasses the `FXMLLoader` *instance* you create entirely, and so the controller property will not be set on that instance. Consequently, if you use that method, `getController()` will return `null`.

On the other hand, if you pass a stream to the [`FXMLLoader.load(InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) instance method, the location property of the `FXMLLoader` instance will not be set. Consequently, some functionality (which you may or may not need; you didn't post the FXML or controller code), such as [location resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution) will not be available.

The most reliable way to use a `FXMLLoader` is to set the location (as a `URL`), and then call the no-argument `load()` method on the `FXMLLoader` instance:

```
private void setupFXMLloader() throws IOException{
    //Set up FXMLloaders
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/smartcal/home/Home.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    //Get an instance of the home controller
    HomeController homeController =  loader.getController();
    homeController.initUserSettingsButton(email_field.getText());

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm!

Comment: You could pass the URL to the constructor of the FXMLLoader

Comment: @Clayn Yes, true; I just thought explicitly calling `setLocation(...)` made it clearer *why* this worked.